# Getting parameter from url in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, zend-route

My route setup :

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
    ->getRouter()
    ->addRoute('view', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('controller/action/:name'))
```

My link in view :

```
$this->url(array("name" => "John"), "view", TRUE);

// returns "controller/action/John" as should
```

Now, when I am at `controller/action/John`, **how do I get the `name` from URL** ? I tried

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam("name");
```

but the name param isn't there - `getRequest()` returns only controller, action and module params.

Comment: Have you tried `$this->getRequest()->getPost()` `$this->getRequest()->getGet()`?

Comment: It is empty - getRequest() checks GET and POST too.

Comment: Probably some other route kicked in. Chechk with `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->getCurrentRouteName()` if the `view` route is actually used

Comment: Yes, the route is set to "default" indeed. Hmm, why doesn't it change to "view", when I use "$this->url(array("name" => "John"), "view", TRUE);" ?

Comment: What you add in the view script doesn't matter. It is the router who checks the URL against the request. If it picks the "default" route it doesn't find a match for your `view` route. The `controller/action` URL must match an existing controller name and action name. What are the real names and do they match?

Comment: The real names of controller/action are offers/view . Yes, they match. Currently, I am doing explode() on the url, to get the parameter, but this is obviously not good

Comment: According to the router there isn't a match. Either you add the route to late or you don't have a controller named `OffersController` with an action named `ViewAction`. For best measures you should also add the defaults to the route.

Comment: By the way, my actions are called indexAction, viewAction etc. Starting with small letter. Maybe it could be the reason somehow? You can add a summary of your comments as an answer - i'll accept it

Comment: small letters is perfect and I believe should not matter. The uppercase was my error in the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set up your route configuration the route definition should either directly match the controller/action names or be set with defaults. Actually setting the defaults in any case is just good practice and helps you avoid issues like this.

So, in your case according to the comments your route should probably look like this.

```
$defaults = array(
    'controller'=> 'offers',
    'action'    => 'view',
    'name'      => ''
);
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('offers/view/:name',$defaults);
```

As mentioned in the comments you can always check what route has been used with `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->getCurrentRouteName()`. If it doesn't show your expected route the Router isn't able to find a match and moves on until it usually ends in the "default" route.

As a side note to your question: When you use `$this->url(array("name" => "John"), "view", TRUE)` you only create the link based on the route. This method is only part of the view and does nothing in terms of dispatching to a controller or action.

Answer (score 0):

For those who found this question and for future reference, you can get params from route using this : `$this->params()->fromRoute('param1', 0);` in Zend Framework 2 at least. This is what I was looking for in this question.